# TensorFlowInferenceInterface having onehot encoded output

Tags: android, neural-network, tensorflow-lite

I have trained a neural network which takes 4 float values as an input and returns one hot encoded output for four class labels.

For eg, {2,12,30,4} -> {0, 0, 1, 0}

The trained model is generated and saved in a .pb file. The model is then imported to asset folder of my android application:

```
inferenceInterface = new TensorFlowInferenceInterface(getAssets(), "tensorflow_lite_xor_nn.pb");
```

I have the following function:

```
private float[] predict(float[] input){
    float output[] = new float[4];

    inferenceInterface.feed("dense_1_input", input, 4, input.length);
    inferenceInterface.run(new String[]{"dense_2/Sigmoid"});
    inferenceInterface.fetch("dense_2/Sigmoid", output);

    return output;
}
```

But I am getting this error:

> java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: buffer with 4 elements is not compatible with a Tensor with shape [4, 4]